# Why pattern "33333.##" acts so strange when we use the DecimalFormat method .format()?

Tags: java, formatting, decimalformat

Yesterday I tried to explore by myself the behavior of DecimalFormat method .format() with all its placeholders and what they do.
So I wrote two numbers and tried different patterns on them. With "#.##" all non-significant zeros were cut and with "0000.00" the method added leading zeros in front of the number. That was OK, but then I tried some strange patterns just to see what would happen.
 
With pattern "33333.##" the final output was really strange. You could see my code below:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("33332.##");
double a= 222.46705219;
double b=-102.000;

System.out.println(df.format(a));
System.out.println(df.format(b));
```

And its output was:

```
 33332222,47
-33332102,0
```

Same input as numbers but with used pattern "33033.##" gave result:

```
33222,4732
33102
```

I understand that the program added the formatted number in the place of 0 but why when zero is not presented as placeholder, the method still rounds the first and (obviously) the second number?
 Why my first number was rounded to its second digit as it has to be, but the second number (b) was printed with a zero at the end?
 And why when the 0-placeholder is presented in the middle of "33033.##" the program inserts formatted number a on its place but doesn't print "33" at the end of number b?
I really don't know how to explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) highlights a clear syntax for the pattern you should be setting.  Both of your formats go against the required syntax, and so your findings should not be seen as reliable, and may change in future versions.  Frankly, I'm surprised that the constructor doesn't throw an exception at these formats.

`33332.##`: The `33332` is seen as a prefix, and the remainder, `.##`, is not valid as either a `0` or a `#` is required before the decimal point.

`33033.##`: The `33` is seen as a prefix, leaving `033.##`.  Given that `0`, `.` nor `#` cannot be part of any prefix or suffix, and `3` can only be part of a prefix or suffix, this pattern is invalid.

Comment: Yeah, I know that they are invalid but that doesn't explain why every pattern treats number a in a different way than  number b. Look at the examples - why pattern "33332.##" prints "a" formatted to the second digit after the decimal separator, but "b" is formatted to the first one?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that, because it is invalid, the result is unpredictable.  It can be for any number of reasons, and there is no reason to believe that it won't change without warning.